# Dirty hack: add property or field to base type in c#?

Tags: c#, security

So this is quite possibly the worst programming question I've asked, and I feel awful.  Really, I do.

Is there a way to recompile a dll, inserting in a public field or property and overwriting a method (one of the constructors) in a class?

I'm using a library that I have to use, but in my opinion, is poorly designed.  Basically we're keeping track of data for people who join a group.

When we create a group in the system, we can specify custom fields we want to keep track of for each member of the group.  In the original system, there was no way to ask members to specify this data themselves when they sign up, so that led to a ton of extra work for our admin staff.  I added a page to do this, however, we have some groups where that data is supposed to be used by the staff alone, so asking the users for it leaves them quite confused.  We need both functionalities.

What I want to do is add a column to the database that keeps track of all these custom fields, and add an "Is visible to public" property to the base class, then hack the constructor that pulls the data from the db to set the property correctly (the constructor already takes a SqlDataReader parameter, so if I can get access to that code, it would only be one extra line).

Ordinarily the hack to get around this is to create a subclass and force the relevant places to use this new class.  Unfortunately, what's used in code is already a set several of subclasses, so the right place to do it would be the base class, as every subclass needs to know whether it can be seen by the public.

So... is what I want to do feasible without a hex editor?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to do this *without the source code*?

Comment: Don't have the time to type it up, and I am not saying it is a good idea to do either (I feel just as dirty as you telling you the answer), but you might want to look in to [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/), it lets you edit the IL code in assemblies and modify them.

Comment: If you're talking about a .Net dll for which you have no source code, then you can dissamble it using ILDAsm.exe, modify the IL, and reassemble it with ILAsm.exe. If the dll is strong name signed there are extra problems involved.

Comment: You say you have the dll but not the code... ? dotnetpeek, .NETReflector... ? Composition is the usual approach for crappy libraries, which I assume you've decided is not possible.

Comment: By the way, regarding your last sentence, I doubt very much that what you want is feasible _with_ a hex editor. :-)

Comment: Yes, I lack the source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off - This sounds like a horrible, unmaintanable approach.

That being said...

There are really two approaches:

1. Decompile the assembly, edit the source, and rebuild it.
2. Use IL weaving via a tool like [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) to change the implementation on disk.

Comment: Fody does not work too well "out of the box" to modify already existing libraries, it is more about rewriting your code at the time of compilation (similar to PostSharp). However the Fody source is a great reference documentation for writing your own methods to do the rewriting.

Comment: With regard to approach #1 have a look at http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/ its free and you can open source code as a compilable project in vs. Make sure with the dll your de compiling there is no licensing implications.

Comment: I ended up using RedGate Reflector + the [reflexil](http://reflexil.net) addon, which uses Scott Chamberlain's suggested Mono.Cecil library.

Now that I've figured out which parts I need to edit--and @ReedCopsey, you're right about my current approach being unmaintanable--I'll write my own patching exe to patch any new versions of the dll we get from the company who wrote the original software.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsVisibleToPublic(this MyBaseClass obj) {
        // implementation here
    }
}
```

The implementation is up to you.  Your implementation could be something simple (albeit inefficient) like making a database call, or it could be more complex, like a lazily loaded static dictionary containing all the `IsVisibleToPublic` values for your system.

Then, all your classes that inherit from `MyBaseClass` will have the `IsVisibleToPublic()` extension method available to them.

Comment: I did consider that.  I guess it's choosing between the lesser of two evils.